# Java: How can I reorder constructor and method arguments quickly in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

This has been bugging me for a while. I'm really pedantic about how my code is formatted, and the order of my member variables is quite important to me.

If I have some Java code like this:

```
private ConverterOne converterOne;
private Dao dao;
private ConverterTwo converterTwo;

public MyClass(ConverterOne converterOne, Dao dao, ConverterTwo converterTwo)
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Is there an eclipse feature or plugin that will easily allow me to change it to this **(without cutting and pasting)**?:

```
private ConverterOne converterOne;
private ConverterTwo converterTwo;
private Dao dao;

public MyClass(ConverterOne converterOne, ConverterTwo converterTwo, Dao dao)
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Ideally I'd like to highlight the constructor argument I want to move and press some command and left/right.

Does this exist, or what alternatives are there?

Comment: I can see why the order of the constructor parameters is important - but *why* is the order of the fields important to you? I would concentrate on training yourself not to care about genuinely-unimportant things, personally. (I know from experience that that can be tricky, but it's worthwhile.)

Comment: I just find it helps when you're processing a class and loading it all into your head to have things in categories that make sense in respect to what that class does. It surprises me that you think it's not important in any sense.

Comment: I think it's not important enough that I'd go out of my way to keep them consistent if it became in *any* way distracting to do so. As noted in the answers, there's tooling to reorder constructor parameters - but that won't change the field ordering.

Comment: Changing the field ordering is easy as they are all on a separate line (Alt + Up/Down). I understand what you're saying, but let's say I have two DAOs at the top of my class, and then a different type after that,. Now I know that there are no more DAOs in this class, as they would be together at the top. Just helps when going back to classes etc and therefore saves time when refreshing your memory.

Answer (score 3):

Select the method in eclipse, right-click > refactor > change method signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can select *Change Method Signature* from the [refactor menu](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) or hit `ALT` + `SHIFT` + `C` with the cursor on the method.

This brings up a dialog that will allow you to easily reorder the method arguments.

Comment: But that doesn't change the field order - it's keeping those in sync which I think will be relatively painful.

Comment: The question wasn't about field order, that's easy. It's keeping the arguments in sync with them that was annoying. Sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your synchronizing needs, but needs manual intervention. All this assumes the field names are always equal to the parameter labels.

We start off with the "wrong order":

```
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;

public SettingsDialog(int a, int b, int c) {
    ...
}
```

Now use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> on the *fields* to change them to the desired order.

```
private int a;
private int c;
private int b;
```

Next, right click on the editor and select `Source > Generate Constructor using Fields ...`, with your cursor above the "wrong" constructor.

The wizard will show the fields in the sequence they appear in the class so you can just leave it as is (or deselect extraneous fields) and click `Finish`.

This will give you a new constructor with the "correct" parameter ordering above your old, wrong constructor:

```
private int a;
private int c;
private int b;

public SettingsDialog(int a, int c, int b) {
    ... //(marker1)
}

public SettingsDialog(int a, int b, int c) { //(marker2)
    ...
}
```

Now place your cursor on the first line of the body of the new constructor (`(marker1)`) and delete all lines via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> until you delete the first line of your old constructor (`(marker2)`). So you delete the entire new body plus the signature of the old constructor. Now the new signature sits atop the body of the old constructor.

This *is* a manuel step, but it's pretty straight forward, satisfies your field-ordering constraint and works for arbitrary complex constructor parameter orderings.

Comment: (important edit: corrected ctrl+up/ctrl+down to read alt+up/alt+down)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. I already do use this system sometimes, but as I said I just wondered if there was a really quick way of shifting things around with a couple of keypresses.